# TS with Redux Slices: valueService.js:205 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'dis' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I can't seem to figure out what's causing the above issue, and debug properly. From my understanding of Redux Slices, I'm able to directly mutate state in my reducer due to the Immer functionality built-in. If I hard code the redux JSON into the UI component there are no issues which leads me to believe it's a Redux issue. Any advice would be appreciated.

Slice.ts

```
interface LoadSchedulerState {
  gridData: DataRow[] | null,
}
interface DataRow {
  id: number,
  dis: string,
  hour: string
}

const initialState: LoadSchedulerState = {
  gridData: null,
}

export const loadSchedulerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'load_scheduler',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateGridData: (state, action:  PayloadAction<DataRow>) => {
      let newData = [{...action.payload}]
      return {...state, gridData:newData}
    },
  },
});

export const {updateGridData} = loadSchedulerSlice.actions;
export const gridData = (state: { loadScheduler: { gridData: any; }; }) => state.loadScheduler.gridData;
export default loadSchedulerSlice.reducer;
```

LoadScheduler.ts

```
import { AgGridColumn, AgGridReact } from "@ag-grid-community/react";
import HeaderGroupComponent from "./HeaderGroupComponent.jsx";
import LoadHeaderComponent from "./LoadHeaderComponent.jsx";
import BtnCellRenderer from './BtnCellRenderer';
import {
  AllModules,
  ColumnApi,
  GridApi,
  GridReadyEvent,
} from "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules";
import "../../styles/DemoGrid.css";
import { updateGridData, gridData } from "./loadSchedulerSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const LoadSchedulerGrid = () => {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState<GridApi>();
  const [columnApi, setColumnApi] = useState<ColumnApi>();
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<any>(null);
  const gridStateData = useSelector(gridData);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  // PUSH TABLE CHANGES VIA WEBSOCKET TO BACKEND 
  const handleCellChange = (event: any) => {
    
  }


  var init_data = {   
    id: 0,
    dis: "Mon 10/19 8:09 A",
    hour: "8 a"
  }

  const dataSetter = (params: { newValue: any; data: any; }) => {
    params.data.dis = params.newValue;
    return false;
  };
  
  const onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
    dispatch(updateGridData(init_data))
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  };

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine demo-grid-wrap">
      <AgGridReact
        onGridReady={(params) => {
          onGridReady(params);
        }}
        immutableData={true}
        rowData={gridStateData}
        getRowNodeId={node => node.id}
        modules={AllModules}
        onCellValueChanged={handleCellChange}
        defaultColDef={{
          resizable: true,
          sortable: true,
          filter: true,
          headerComponentFramework: LoadHeaderComponent,
          headerComponentParams: {
            menuIcon: "fa-bars",
          },
        }}
      >

        <AgGridColumn headerName="#" width={50} checkboxSelection sortable={false} suppressMenu filter={false} pinned></AgGridColumn>

        <AgGridColumn headerName="Load Details" headerGroupComponentFramework={HeaderGroupComponent}>
          <AgGridColumn field="dis" width={110} headerName="Dispatch" editable  cellClass="dispatch" valueSetter={dataSetter} />
          <AgGridColumn field="hour" width={50} headerName="Hour" cellClass="hour" />
        </AgGridColumn>

      </AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};

const rules = {
  dc_rules:{
    "cell-blue": (params: { value: string }) => params.value === 'ERD',
    "cell-beige": (params: {value: string }) => params.value === 'PDC',
    "cell-cyan": (params: {value: string }) => params.value === 'CRD'
  },
  nr_cube_rules:{
    "cell-red": (params: {value: number }) => params.value > 10.0
  }
}

export default LoadSchedulerGrid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ag-grid per default tries to directly mutate the state object outside of a reducer. You have to use Ag-Grids `immutableData` setting.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/immutable-data/

They even have a blog article about using RTK with Ag-Grid (even if they use immutable logic in the reducers - within the RTK reducers this is not necessary as you correctly noted): https://blog.ag-grid.com/adding-removing-rows-columns-ag-grid-with-react-redux-toolkit/

Comment: I've added the immutable data type as well as the getRowID function, yet the error is still persistent. I've tried following tutorial and still stuck. Any further help would be appreciated. I'm able to load in data from the store successfully, just fails once I edit a cell ( even without calling an onCellChange handler).

Comment: Can you update your code examples and maybe even provide a reproduction?

Comment: Code samples in the question have been updated.

Comment: You will need to write a `valueSetter` method on your column and that one **has** to `return false` in the end, otherwise ag-grid will still try to write on the object.

Comment: I've updated the sample code with a dataGetter method and a call to it in the necessary column. However, I'm still receiving the initial error. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot modify the object directly in that dataSetter method, as it is in Redux state and you can only ever modify Redux state by dispatching an action. (So you would have to dispatch here...) Are you sure you want to keep it in Redux here in the first place? Keeping it in local component state might do better in this use case.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, thank you so much !